# Найти угол между линией и осью Х

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно найти угол между линией заданной двумя точками и осью Х, считая первую точку линии за начало координат.
У меня есть код:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y = [5369.1306, 5375.72924976, 5371.5215, 5378.77635263, 5370.3801, 5368.1303, 5368.09620001, 5375.3064, 5362.01, 5360.03306003, 5362.87066287, 5378.05787462, 5370, 5378.94617887, 5379, 5374.9357, 5379.99999999, 5379.99999981, 5379.99999981, 5375]
x = range(len(y))
ugol= np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y[-4] - y[-3], x[-4] - x[-3]))
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

Почему-то выводит : -89.99998968676454 и [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вообще значения могут быть только в 1 и 4 четвертях. Угол между линией и осью Х в точках x[-4] и x[-3], значения которых 5379.99999999, 5379.99999981 соответственно, должен составлять около 0 градусов.
А например, между точками x[-2] и x[-1], значения которых 5379.99999981 и 5375, угол должен быть между -45 и -90(выводит -11.309932892719736).
Ps: Может я чего-то не понимаю? У меня с углами всегда были проблемы.

Comment: А что вы хотели сказать приведенным графиком? Это значения вашего `x`, отмеченные по оси `y`. И что?

Comment: Я написал, что мой код выводит. А на графике видно видно, что угол между линией образованной точками x[-4], x[-3] и началом координат(точкой x[-4]) примерно 0 градусов. Однако выводит  -89.99998968676454.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что вы неправильно генерируете график? что у вас ось x - по вертикали?

Comment: Я понял о чем вы говорите и разобрался в чем у меня была ошибка благодаря вам. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны понимать, что нахождение углов сводится к определению арктангенса для сторон каждого маленького прямоугольного треугольника, где один катет - разница между координатами `x` точки, а второй - разница между координатами `y`. Поскольку у вас приращение по `y` равно 1, то я ввел массив `np.ones`. А приращения по `x` вычислил c помощью `np.diff`. Итого, получаем:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = [5369.1306, 5375.72924976, 5371.5215, 5378.77635263, 5370.3801, 5368.1303, 5368.09620001, 5375.3064, 5362.01, 5360.03306003, 5362.87066287, 5378.05787462, 5370, 5378.94617887, 5379, 5374.9357, 5379.99999999, 5379.99999981, 5379.99999981, 5375]
y = range(len(x))

xdelta = np.diff(x)
res = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(np.ones(len(x)-1), xdelta))
print(res)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y)
for i in y:
    plt.annotate(y[i], (x[i]+.2, y[i]-.3))
    plt.axhline(y=i, color="red", linestyle='-.', linewidth=0.7)

for i in range(len(x)-1):    
    plt.annotate("{0:.2f}".format(res[i]), (x[i]-.2, y[i]+.3), color="green")

plt.show()
```

На выходе:

```
[  8.61738469 166.63128199   7.84812585 173.20802371 156.03562072
  91.95302874   7.89611794 175.69897736 153.16824215  19.4129742
   3.76719521 172.92563777   6.37802159  86.91924879 166.17723853
  11.16996664  90.00001031  90.         168.69006711]
```

Ну и график (углы - зеленым)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]